# How do I use jQuery UI's sortable functionality on a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

hello friend i found this code from this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) . when i add more data in any of `<li>` it become overflow . `<li>` height is define in `css` when i remove the height its not working perfectly .I tried to convert it into table rows but I fail to do this please tell me the solution . I want to add more and more data in any of `<li>`

Thanks friends

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to add more data to the `<li>`, I would suggest you to use `<div>` rather than an `<li>` and then use `overflow` in the CSS. In a table if you have sortable then in that case dont use `table`. `<td>` within a `table` can be sorted but not outside of that 
`table`. I have a sample code where I have sone it in a bunch of div's. Check it out on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/jYFRB/

Comment: hello shiv thanks for help but i dont want pop up's . i want dragable rows.

Comment: In case of tables <td> 's become sortable. For making rows Sortable try to make a structure within a <li> or <div> with some ID so that it becomes sortable. As in the entire row.

Comment: I have the best solution for you. Its a website with this demo on how to make the table row sortable http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/   check it out!!